# Modified cookie doesn't reach Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, cookies, websocket, gateway

### **Hello**

So I have been working on websocket project and decided to add authorization to it. I came up with an idea that i can add cookie variable named X-Authorization on my client side, and im doing it like this

1. **TypeScript implementation**

```
async connectToWebSocket():Promise<void> {
      const token = await this.keycloakService.getToken();
      this.cookieService.set('X-Authorization', token);
        this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://url_address:8080/path");
}
```

---

Request is going through Spring Cloud Gateway and is being forwarded to downstream service that handles taking token from given cookie and put it in proper header in OncePerRequest filter like this

2. **Java implementation**

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request,@NotNull HttpServletResponse response,@NotNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Filtering request");
        String token = extractTokenFromRequest(request);
        log.info("extracted token");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            log.info("Passing to next filter");
            filterChain.doFilter(new TokenHttpServletRequestWrapper(request, token), response);
        } else {
            throw new TokenRetrieveException("No token provided", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    private String extractTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("getting cookie");
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            log.info("cookie not null");
            Optional<Cookie> tokenCookie = Arrays.stream(cookies)
                    .filter(cookie -> "X-Authorization".equals(cookie.getName()))
                    .findFirst();
            if (tokenCookie.isPresent()) {
                return tokenCookie.get().getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

3. **Problem starts here**

When I start everything up from docker compose with local addresses (localhost:8080 etc.) everything works fine and cookies are being send to cloud gateway and then to downstream service that handles it, in short - no problem.

But when i set everything up(change addresses from localhost to server address) to run docker compose on Azure VM when i send same request with same cookie it doesn't even reach Spring Cloud Gateway and it's being deleted somewhere and I have no idea what to search for.

---

What are your ideas about it and what can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use a different name instead of `X-Authorization` , for example `my-cookie` and see if that gets forwarded or also removed?

I would think that somewhere in Azure something (Gateway?) is removing all those headers for security reason.

This is just speculation

Comment: I didn't, gonna try it in a while